# Analyse TypeScript SonarQube in Maven project

Tags: maven, typescript, sonarqube

I'll try to use the SonarQube SonarTS plugin to analyse TypeScript files in a project of mine.

It contains a submodule that contains some images, some xmls, and a couple of .ts-files. I have installed SonarTS ( https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarTS ) in SonarQube. The project uses typescript 2.4.2 as a devDependency and is build with Node 6.13.1.

When I call `mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.branch=<BRANCHNAME>` (I know sonar.branch is deprecated, I'll fix soon :)), eventually the sum-module is scanned and this is the log:

```
[INFO] -------------  Scan MyProject
[INFO] Base dir: /home/jenkins/workspace/my-project/my-project-config-model
[INFO] Working dir: /home/jenkins/workspace/my-project/my-project-config-model/target/sonar
[INFO] Source paths: pom.xml
[INFO] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
[INFO] Index files
[INFO] 1 file indexed
[INFO] Quality profile for xml: Sonar way
[INFO] Sensor Embedded CSS Analyzer Sensor [css]
[INFO] 0 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] Sensor Embedded CSS Analyzer Sensor [css] (done) | time=1ms
[INFO] Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java]
[INFO] 0/0 source files have been analyzed
[INFO] 1 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java] (done) | time=31ms
[INFO] 1/1 source files have been analyzed
[INFO] Sensor XML Sensor [xml]
[INFO] Sensor XML Sensor [xml] (done) | time=8ms
[INFO] SCM provider for this project is: git
[INFO] 1 files to be analyzed
[INFO] 0/1 files analyzed
```

And the only file that is scanned is the pom.xml

Could it have something to do with the structure of the sub-module? The xmls and ts files are not at `src/main/{ts|resources}`, but `src/models` and `src/scripts`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you need to change the `sonar.sources` parameter to include your source folders (something like `sonar.sources=src/main/java,src/models,src/scripts` should work).

You can find more about analysis parameters [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters), and more about the way to configure the maven scanner [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven).

Comment: Thank you very much! Have seen that in some examples, but haven't found the info, that if empty the default maven values are used. Thanks!